# How to escape special characters in RODBC connection string password

Tags: r, shiny, rodbc

I have a SQL Server database to which I can connect with my user and this password: "testspecialcharacters_¤"  through MS Studio without problems. We are using windows authentication to connect to the server.

However I cannot connect to it through my R Shiny app. I cannot give the exact server, database and user names but this is very close to the code I am using:

```
library(RODBCext)
ch <- odbcDriverConnect("DSN=test;database=test_db;UID=test_user;PWD=testspecialcharacters_¤")
data <- sqlQuery(ch,"select * from test_db.general.test_tbl")
```

I receive the following error:

```
[RODBC] ERROR: state 42000, code 18452, message [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.
[RODBC] ERROR: state 08001, code 0, message [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source
ODBC connection failed
```

I have to mention that the same code works for passwords without that special character. From experience we have found out that "-" and "!" seem to work. However "@" and "¤" do not work. We have not tried all the potential special characters, only these few.

Based on different other posts online I have tried the following, with no success:

```
ch <- odbcDriverConnect("DSN=test;database=test_db;UID=test_user;PWD=testspecialcharacters_¤", DBMSencoding = "UTF-8")
ch <- odbcDriverConnect("DSN=test;database=test_db;UID=test_user;PWD=testspecialcharacters_¤", DBMSencoding = "UTF-8-BOM")
ch <- odbcDriverConnect("DSN=test;database=test_db;UID=test_user;PWD=testspecialcharacters_¤", DBMSencoding = "latin1")
ch <- odbcDriverConnect("DSN=test;database=test_db;UID=test_user;PWD={testspecialcharacters_¤}")
ch <- odbcDriverConnect("DSN=test;database=test_db;UID=test_user;PWD='testspecialcharacters_¤'")
```

I am using RStudio Pro with UTF-8 default encoding.

Does anybody know how to escape the special characters used in the password string? Or if a different way of connecting to the database is needed.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use basic escaping like this. But you have to test it on your machine, because setting correct encoding between your machine and database is really hard.

```
x <- "¤"


y <- "\u00A4"

identical(x, y) # true
```

And link for table
https://www.utf8-chartable.de/

Comment: Hi, thank you for your suggestion, I just tried it out but this also seems to not work. I have changed my connection string to ch <- odbcDriverConnect("DSN=test;database=test_db;UID=test_user;PWD={testspecialcharacters_\u00A4}") --- it looks like R knows how to convert "\u00A4" back to "¤" but the connection to the server is still not allowed, I am getting the same error as before.